# How to match and rewrite part of a URL string using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have changed the method in which my site works, yet I want it to be backwards compatible for saved URLs

If a users has "play?" in the URL, I'd like the site to actually direct to "play&"

i.e. http://domain.com/play?v=foo&s=bar becomes http://domain.com/play&v=foo&s=bar

Thanks,

Mike

Edit:

/play is already being treated as a $z variable in .htaccess using these rewrite rules which may affect proposed solutions:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?z=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `?` denotes the start of the query string so `play?` will never really be in the URL, they're separate things. Equally, using `&v=foo&s=bar..` without being after `?` probably won't work unless you've written something custom to parse it

Comment: @arco444 - you're right, the play folder is now a htaccess redirect of domain.com?z=play followed by variables - however it used to be an actual folder and I'm trying to retain working hyperlinks for people who have them saved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?z=(play)(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?z=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This isn't working I'm afraid - I wonder if it's due to play already being rewritten from domain.com?z=play - see my comment above

Comment: Can you show your rule that is rewriting `play` URLs.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the rewrite rules into the original question